# C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Здравствуйтe, помогите разобраться пожалуйста 
Надо по первым 3 символам или больше в textBox найти записи в базе данных и отобразить их в Listbox.
Есть код

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Model1 db;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        db = new Model1();
        db.OrdersBs.Load();
        db.refdets.Load();
        textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
    }

    public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        int s = textBox1.Text.Count();
        if (s > 2)
        {
            var customers25 = db.refdets.Local.Where(c => c.partnumber.StartsWith(str));
            int count = db.refdets.Local.Count;
            if (count > 0)
            {
                foreach (refdet c in customers25)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(c.partnumber + c.descript + c.price.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но после введения 3 символов выполнение зависает. Предполагаю что это из-за того , что слишком много записей в таблице или неправильный код

Comment: Сколько записей в базе? Сколько записей возвращается?

Comment: 78 записей возвращается

Comment: не всего, а начинающиеся на  001

Comment: Всего записей в этой таблице, откуда идет выборка 247742

Comment: Вы точки останова поставьте и проверьте как код выполняется.

Answer (score 3):

Сделайте метод `textBox1_TextChanged` асинхронным. В вашем случае, он может выглядеть так:

```
public async void textBox1_TextChangedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    int s = textBox1.Text.Count();
    if (s > 2)
    {
        // Асинхронно получаем данные
        var customers25 = await db.refdets.Where(c => c.partnumber.StartsWith(str)).ToListAsync();

        foreach (var c in customers25)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(c.partnumber + c.descript + c.price.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```